# Moving a button in a circle

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton

Is it possible to make a button move in a constant circle around an image on an iPhone screen?

Comment: Many things are possible, and this is one of them. It would be more helpful for us answering questions if you posted your efforts to accomplish them and a specific problem. That being said, look into UIBezierPath.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. You could use the UIView method `animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`, with an options values of CalculationModeCubic + Repeat , and control-points evenly spaced around a circle.

Alternately you could use the more complex CAKeyframeAnimation class.

I have a demo app written in Objective-C that creates a sine wave type animation using both methods that I can post if you know how to read Objective-C. It should help you get started.

### EDIT See this github archive:

https://github.com/DuncanMC/KeyframeViewAnimations

Note that there is a bug in UIView keyframe animation (fixed in iOS 9) that causes your object to not follow your curve correctly in some cases. The bug and a fix for it is discussed in the markdown document Sleuthing UIView animations.md which is included in that github archive.

Comment: Can you please post it? That would be a huge help. I am trying to get a head start for next year's WWDC scholarship! I am also able to write in Objective-C.